# Cerrar sesión en Firebase (Kotlin)

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firestore, firebase-auth, jetpack-compose

Tengo un proyecto usando Kotlin y Jetpack compose. En este caso lo que tengo es una pantalla de login con Firebase y Google. El proyecto guarda los datos de sesión luego de la autenticación. Luego de cerrar la app y volverla a abrir se iniciaba automáticamente debido a que se consultaba si existe en Firebase.

Seguido, implementé un botón que cierra la sesión y lo que quiero es que el usuario vuelva al login (esto ya se cumple) pero quiero que pueda volver a tener la opción de elegir de entre las cuentas de Google que tenga disponible en su móvil.

Esto no pasa y el el logueo se realiza automáticamente con el ultimo usuario que inició la sesión.

Ya confirmé que el uid en Firebase existe y coincide.
Las variables para la comprobación son estas

```
  val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
  val currentUser = auth.currentUser
  val driverID = currentUser?.uid ?: ""
```

El botón que uso cierra la sesión y envia al usuario al login como comenté pero no presenta la pantalla de selección de cuentas de Google y no encuentro como hacer esto.

Este es el código de mi botón donde tengo la única manera de cerrar la sesión en todo el proyecto hasta ahora

```
      modifier = Modifier.clickable {
        auth.signOut()
        navController.navigate(Screens.LoginScreen.name) {
          popUpTo(Screens.LoginScreen.name) {
            inclusive = true
          }
        }
      },
```

Ahora, en revisando el logcat veo este mensaje que tal vez pueda ser el causante de no permitir el cierre de sesión en Firebase.

```
Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
Error Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but drivers has 1
```

En caso de ser así no comprendo como puedo iniciar la sesión y guardar los datos con el mismo nombre de documento pero no poderle utilizar para cerrar la sesion.

Había encontrado otro hilo que hablaba de revocar los accesos pero no es lo que busco.

Si tienen algún hilo donde pueda encontrar algo me ayudaría mucho.
Les agradezco por el tiempo.